# Streaming hls video from s3

Tags: go, amazon-s3, stream, video-streaming

I need have hls video chunks in s3 bucket, I need to stream it to frontend. From front side it is fairly easy-they just send get request to  `video/filename` and I need to give the, file back. The thing is that if I do it in standard way then it will download to my server file, saving it to buffer, than it will send to front, that's not very good. Instead of this I want to "stream" it, so when, say, 1000 bytes arrive I send it immediately to front, not waiting for complete donwload.
The question is how can I do this? I thought that if I use `copy(responseWriter, response.Body)`, than it will actually send response, but will it stream? Should I use reverse proxy? Is there any solution using fasthttp?

Comment: "but will it stream?" That depends on your definition of  "stream". "Is there any solution using fasthttp?" No.

Comment: I mean not waiting until whole object dowloads to my server and then upload it to frontend but instead do it continuely, for ex I've received 1000 bytes-I push it to frontend, I've received next 1000 bytes-I've push it to frontend, so when I will receive last N bytes from s3 storage, I just need to send these bytes to frontend at one iteration instead of uploading whole file at once

Answer (score -1):

`io.Copy` uses a 32kB buffer internally. If this is too big for your streaming (or if you want to rate limit your streaming) just implement that for loop which reads from upstream and writes to downstream yourself. Peeking at the implementation of io.Copy is trivial, so what is your actual question?